# Flatten AcroForm using pdfSharp to reduce file size

Tags: c#, pdf, pdfsharp

Currently I have a couple of PDF files including filled acro forms. For reporting purpose I need to get the file size reduced.
So I'm searching for pdfsharp functionalities to remove the acroform fields (flatten?) hoping that it will reduce the total file sizes.

Is there any possibility using pdfSharp?

As far as I could see, iTextSharp is providing some mechanisms...

**Update (due to the -1 rating):**

Yes of course does flattening have other results. That was only a thought from my side. The idea behind that is, that acroforms is a really good feature that enables the software to use pdf as (quite performant) templates. And all departments are able to prepare that. But on the composite, these AcroFields causes that teh pdf docs are much bigger. For reporting purpose I don't need the form fields.

Comment: I generally wouldn't expect form flattening to result in a considerable size reduction. Unless, probably, an optimization of embedded fonts for the forms also takes place...

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to PDF's "flattening" the acrofields will make the fields readonly. It won't remove them from the document. This becomes apparent if you set the value of the fields before flattening them. The values of the fields will be printed where the fields were located they just won't be changeable.

If that's what you want you can do it with PDFSharp

```
PdfDocument doc = PdfReader.Open(filePath, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Modify);
doc.Flatten();
```

This will flatten the acrofields which will make them readonly.
I just tried it out, it does not seem to decrease the file size. 
So I'm not sure this is the solution you were searching for, but in response to your question. Yes. It is possible to flatten Acroform using PDfSharp.